# flutter how to apply linear gradient in Dotted Border?

Tags: flutter

Flutter how to apply linear gradient in DottedBorder? I want make this below attachment UI design.I do not understand how to make it.I am biginner please give me any solution.

[image]

But this is what I made. See this below ui design and my code..
If we can not use linear gradient in dotted border then how can I make this Ui design in another way?Please suggest.

[image]

```
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class Test extends StatefulWidget {
      const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
    }
    class _TestState extends State<Test> {
      List status = [1, 2, 5, 4, 9, 13, 15, 20, 30, 40, 80];
      double radius = 27.0;
      double colorWidth(double radius, int statusCount, double separation) {
        return ((2 * pi * radius) - (statusCount * separation)) / statusCount;
      }
      double separation(int statusCount) {
        if (statusCount <= 20)
          return 3.0;
        else if (statusCount <= 30)
          return 1.8;
        else if (statusCount <= 60)
          return 1.0;
        else
          return 0.3;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body:
            ListView.separated(
              itemCount: status.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 15,
              ),
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) =>
                  Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child:
                    CustomPaint(
                      child: DottedBorder(
                        color: Colors.teal.shade300,
                        borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
    
                        dashPattern: status[index] == 1
                            ? [
                          //one status
                          (2 * pi * (radius + 2)),
                          0,
                        ]
                            : [
                          colorWidth(radius + 2, status[index],
                              separation(status[index])),
                          separation(status[index]),
                        ],
                        strokeWidth: 3,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: radius,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: radius - 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${status[index]}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```